# How to solved FileNotFoundError in python while using Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am learning how to do data analysis using Python. I was trying to import a csv file with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('data_set/Excel_1.csv')
```

I triple-checked the name of the folder and the file. I will post its photo as well for more insight.

[This is how my data folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhi0Y.png)

When I try to run it, the code says I have a FileNotFoundError

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-3-400077328cf5> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('data_set/Excel_1.csv')

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-                
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, 
delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, 
mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, 
skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, 
keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, 
infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, 
cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, 
lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, 
encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, 
low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    460 
    461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    463 
    464     if chunksize or iterator:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = 
kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: 
ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1865 
   1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
   1868         assert self.handles is not None
   1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", 
"compression"):

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
   1366             compression=kwds.get("compression", None),
   1367             memory_map=kwds.get("memory_map", False),
-> 1368             storage_options=kwds.get("storage_options", None),
   1369         )
   1370 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py 
in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, 
is_text, errors, storage_options)
    645                 encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    646                 errors=errors,
--> 647                 newline="",
    648             )
    649         else:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'data_set/Excel_1.csv'
```

How should I resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: The error is not visible

Comment: Sorry about it. I just noticed and corrected it.

Comment: Error stacks should always be pasted as text. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask